# Proving convexity of a set through intersection with a line

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis

I know that we can prove that a function $f $ is convex by proving that it is convex when it is evaluated on any arbitrary line that intersects its domain.

However, can we prove the convexity of a set by proving the convexity of a function  evaluated in any arbitrary line of the set? Because I saw this in a class, but I am a bit confused because in this way we proved the convexity of the function, and not of the set, right?

I am wondering if the convexity of the set follows from the convexity of the function, since a necessary condition for a function to be convex is the convexity of its domain. 
For example:

$$C= \{x \mid f(x) := x^TQx + q^Tx +c \le 0\}$$

with $Q$ **positive semi-definite**.

Can I show that the function $g(t)=f(b+tv)$ is convex and conclude that C is convex? If yes, why? My logic would say to prove that $g(t)\le0$ for $t$ that is an admissible point. And I can prove this, say, applying the definition (i.e. taking $t1, t2$) belonging to the set.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$
   f(x) = x^TQx + b^Tx + c
$$
where $Q$ is PSD.

To prove that $f$ is convex provided that $g(t)=f(b + tv)$ is convex for $b$ and $v$ arbitrary proceed as follows.

Take $x,y\in{\mathbf R}^n$ and $0\le\theta\le1$. Put $z = \theta x + (1-\theta)y$. We have to show that
$$
    f(z)\le\theta f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y).
$$
Now define $g(t) = f(b + tv)$, where $b = y$ and $v = x - y$. By hypothesis, $g$ is convex. Therefore
\begin{align*}
         f(z) &= f(y + \theta(x-y))\\
              &=g(\theta) \\
              &= g(\theta1 + (1-\theta)0)\\
              &\le \theta g(1) + (1-\theta)g(0) \\
              &= \theta f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y).
\end{align*}
(*Once we fix $x$ and $y$ all that concerns to the definition of convexity lines on the line segment that joins $x$ with $y$. This is why the convexity of $g$ is equivalent to the convexity of $f$.*)

Now, once you know that $f$ is convex (by whatever means), you can show that
$$
    C = \{x\mid f(x)\le0\}
$$
is convex too. Take $x,y,\theta$ and $z$ as above. We have
$$
  f(z) \le \theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(y)
                            \le \theta 0 + (1-\theta)0
                             =0,
$$
which shows that $\theta x + (1-\theta)y\in C$.

**Note:** *you can use the same reasoning when replacing $0$ in $C$ with any real number $\alpha$. Also, you should picture the fact that these *sub-level* sets (this is how they are called) are convex by drawing a convex function (such as $x^2$) and visualizing them in the domain.*

Comment: Thank you. I already had clear that convexity of $g$ implies convexity of $f$ (although I never proved it). I think that is more correct to say that is the line segment between the 2 points that makes the function convex (not the line). The last part is what I really searched, that is, showing the convexity of the set by exploiting the knowledge that the function is convex. But this make me think a bit..  $f$ is convex if the domain is convex, so it should be non sense to demonstrate that the domain is convex. But I think that we are assuming that the set C is a (sub-)set of the domain. Right?

Comment: And one more thing: you defined the function $f$, but not the domain. So we implicitly consider is $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, sub-level sets are defined as subsets of dom $f$. In this particular case the domain is ${\mathbf R}^n$, so there is no need to clarify that.

Comment: Should not we make some assumption on the domain of $g$?

Comment: Not exactly an assumption, rather an observation. Given that $b+tv$ must belong in dom $f$ it must be dom $g=\{t \mid b+tv \in {\rm dom}\,f\}$. Because of the convexity of dom $f$, a sufficient condition for this to happen is to restrict $t$ to a suitable interval. Since usually $v$ is chosen to by the difference between two points in the domain, having $t\in[0,1]$ would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

A function is convex if and only if the [epigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics)) of the function is convex. If a set is the epigraph of some function you can prove that it's convex by proving the function is convex.

Comment: And how do you relate with the example above?

Comment: @Alberto it's a simple way to understand the relationship between convex functions and the convex sets associated with them. Formulating the problem in terms of epigraphs reveals that the affine action on the domain given by $b+tv$ merely changes the origin of the graph. Since the origin is an arbitrary choice on convex sets $g(t)$ is convex if and only if $f(x)$ is convex.